# How to update a database table data from an PHP array?

Tags: php, mysql, database, sql-update

I need to update the information of a mysql table database from a php array.

I'm looking for the best approach to do this, what I want to do is to update an existing database table with new information, this means that there could be new rows, the existing rows could have new values in their fields, or rows deleted.

The approaches that I am thinking are:

1. Erase all the data and rows from the current table and insert again all the rows with the most updated data provided by the php array. But I don't know if this is an expensive approach or indeed it is used.
2. Another idea that I have is that maybe I could check if the field values from the rows had changed and if it is the case update then the values, also check the order of the rows to check if some rows were deleted and the order changed, and lastly insert new rows if it is the case, but i think this get really tricky and messy.

What do you think? Some ideas for the better approach?
Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) to `INSERT` new rows and `UPDATE` existing rows.

**Example:**

```
INSERT INTO t1 (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE a=1,b=2,c=3;
```

You have to build `DELETE` statement using some trick in php.

**Example:**

```
<?php

$data = array(
    array( 'a'=>1, 'b'=>2, 'c'=>3 ),
    array( 'a'=>4, 'b'=>5, 'c'=>6 ),
    array( 'a'=>7, 'b'=>8, 'c'=>9 ),
);

$condition = implode( ',', array_map( function($temp){return sprintf("('%s','%s','%s')",$temp['a'],$temp['b'],$temp['c']);},$data));
$sql = "DELETE FROM t1 WHERE (a,b,c) NOT IN (" . $condition . ");";
echo $sql; // DELETE FROM t1 WHERE (a,b,c) NOT IN (('1','2','3'),('4','5','6'),('7','8','9'));

// OR

$condition1 = implode( ',', array_map( function($temp){return sprintf("'%s'",$temp['a']);},$data));
$sql1 = "DELETE FROM t1 WHERE a NOT IN (" . $condition1 . ");";
echo $sql1; // DELETE FROM t1 WHERE a NOT IN ('1','4','7');

?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , Now I have clear about insert and update. Now I will analyze the delete part :) ;)

Answer (score 1):

The DBMS can do this for you. Just use the command:

```
  'INSERT INTO table ({target list}) VALUES({values}) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE val1={value} , val2={value},...'
```

Comment: Thanks, alessandroAmedei. Does it take in account if rows were deleted, also this will add new rows? Or I Will have to execute  the instruction you said for updating the values and after that insert the new rows?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, there is a light in the way hehe @alessandroAmedei

Comment: This command will add a row if the row is not in the table, otherwise it will update the row. I think in your php array you know where there is the primary key of your data you want to delete. In this case just use the command DELETE

Comment: If a row was deleted, it would not be in the php array, so I have to detect in the table that I want to update that the row no longer exists, and then delete it.

Comment: Ok if you want to "save" all the rows that you have deleted you need another table I guess.